# Forcing use of UInt32 in simple Fibonacci formula gives compiler error

Tags: crystal-lang

> I'm posting both question and answer here for others to find since I wrongly asked this in the Crystal-lang issue tracker, and it's better suited here for others to search and find

I try to use unsigned integer in a simple fibonacchi calculation like this:

```
def fibonacchi(n : UInt32) : UInt32
  if n == 0
    puts "Invalid number."
  elsif n == 1
    return 0
  elsif n == 2
    return 1
  else
    return fibonacchi(n - 1).as(UInt32) + fibonacchi(n - 2).as(UInt32)
  end
  return 0
end

n = 45_u32
res = fibonacchi(n)
puts res
```

I have also tried:

```
n = 45.as(UInt32)
```

If i puts `typeof(n)` it shows the type as "UInt32"
[image]

I know i have a lot of unnecessary type-declarations, but I put them on to try localize where the error came from. What do I do wrong?

OS: macOS 10.13.6
Compiler version: crystal 0.25.1 LLVM: 5.0.2

Answer (score 2):

I'll give credit to @asterite, @ysbaddaden and @straight-shoota for answering the question I had:

The issue was that I return 0 and 1 that are `Int32` by default, you must specify them as `UInt32`. This will work:

```
def fib(n : UInt32) : UInt32
  case n
  when 0, 1
    0_u32
  when 2
    1_u32
  else
    fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
  end
end

p fib(45)
```

And to give a warning about the second thing I tried: `n = 45.as(UInt32)`

And `#as(UInt32)` won't convert from `Int32` to `UInt32`. It will just treat the value as if it was a UInt32 which is highly unsafe. A proper type conversion is performed by `#to_u32`.

**EDIT**

Turns out that `Int32#as(UInt32)`will not even compile. In my case it was just the compiler message that stopped at the first mistake before it even noticed the invalid cast.